Why does the session id not match redis key?
I am using redis as my session store in net core.
This is a standard setup as per most articles.
        services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
        {
            options.Configuration = host;
            options.InstanceName = name;
        });

Here is my code to write the value to redis.
    private ISession Session => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;

    public async Task SetAsync<T>(string key, T value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key and value must be provided");
        try
        {
            await Session.LoadAsync();
            Session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
            await Session.CommitAsync();
        }
        catch
        {
            _logger.LogError("Session store unavailable cannot commit session");
        }
    }

If I read the value of Session.Id from httpContext I get the session id as expected.
b0208014-03da-9fc2-e444-791aa5e5ab3c
However, using redis-cli to view the keys, this is nowhere to be found. The redis key for this is:
"localc7c334a7-b3df-e981-438f-d5cadb0a904d"
I read an article that explains the instance name is prefixed to the key, however, everything I read suggestions the rest should match the session id.
What am I missing?

Hi Alik, obviously the key is prefixed with local, so please try this command, redis-cli KEYS "*b0208014-03da-9fc2-e444-791aa5e5ab3c*"
to see if it can be found.

@JasonPan, of course that was tried and as you can see from my question the keys are different.

The JsonConverter value is whatever is going inot Redis that is not the issue.  The simple issue as mentioned is KEYS * returns keys that do not match session.id from context.  I have a feeling that the standard call to Session.SetString is Hashing the session id.  But without looking at the underlying implementation of the internal classes used I cannot confirm.

Hi Alik, I just realized this, so I deleted it. My original intention was to say that before calling the public async Task SetAsync<T>(string key, T value) method, the value of key is consistent with the Key  before invoking the Session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));.

Hi @JasonPan correct, the value of the key is that data key for example: _customerInfo, so either the provider is hashing the cookie value or i have some additional debugging to do as I noticed we have multiple middlewares so one of them might be changing the session id.

I also use Redis Server, but I have never seen an error like this. I can show you my custom service for for using Redis, which works.
Note that I prefer to add keys for logic, so that
if you’re need to get drivers, you can set a key like "drivers", and you can add custom method to check whether this key exists or not, and, if not, call call a function from any GetDrivers() service method and send the data to Redis.
In Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(redis =>
{
    redis.InstanceName = host;
    redis.Configuration = name;
});
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICacheService, CacheManger>();

In ICacheService:
public interface ICacheService
{
    T GetData<T>(string key);
    bool SetData<T>(string key,T data ,DateTimeOffset date);
    bool RemoveData(string key);  
}

In CacheManager:
public sealed class CacheManger : ICacheService
    {
        private readonly ConnectionMultiplexer _connection;
        private readonly IDatabase _cacheDb; 
        public CacheManger()
        {
            _connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(new ConfigurationOptions(){
                EndPoints = {host},
                ClientName = name,
            });

            _cacheDb = _connection.GetDatabase(); 
        }


        public T GetData<T>(string key)
        {
            var value = _cacheDb.StringGet(key);
            if(value.HasValue)
                return  JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(value);

            return default;
        } 

        public bool RemoveData(string key)
        {
            if (_cacheDb.KeyExists(key))
                return  _cacheDb.KeyDelete(key);
            return false;
        }

        public bool SetData<T>(string key, T data, DateTimeOffset date)
        {
            var expire = date.DateTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
            return _cacheDb.StringSet(key,JsonSerializer.Serialize(data),expire); 
        }
    }

